# How to insert image url in mysql database using constructor function

Tags: php, oop, constructor

I am beginner in php and i wish to send image url in database using constructors function . before i used ordinary php and it worked fine .

The following file works great :

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    $image = $_POST['image'];
            $name = $_POST['name'];

    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    $sql ="SELECT id FROM uploadimagestoserver ORDER BY id ASC";

    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $id = 0;

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            $id = $row['id'];
    }

    $path = "uploads/$id.png";

    $actualpath = "https://localhost/GoodPriceApi/uploadImage/$path";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO uploadimagestoserver(image,name) VALUES ('$actualpath','$name')";

    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));
        echo "Successfully Uploaded";
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
}else{
    echo "Error";
}
?>
```

But when i try to add my script in the following function i get an error :
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Please help me to integrate up mentioned codes in this function **createProfile** which is file i nemed DbHandler.php and another one i named               upload.php

**DbHandler.php**

```
class DbHandler {

private $conn;

function __construct() {
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/DbConnect.php';
    // opening db connection
    $db = new DbConnect();
    $this->conn = $db->connect();
}

public function createProfile($image, $name) {

 $response = array();

 $stmt =$this->conn->prepare ("SELECT id FROM uploadimagestoserver ORDER BY     id ASC") ;

   $id = 0;

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){
            $id = $row['id'];
    }

    $path = "uploads/$id.png";
    $actualpath = "https://localhost/GoodPriceApi/uploadImage/$path";


        // insert query
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO uploadimagestoserver(image,name) values(?, ?)");
     $stmt->bind_param("is", $actualpath, $name);

        $result = $stmt->execute();

        $new_user_id = $stmt->insert_id;

        $stmt->close();

        // Check for successful insertion
        if ($result) {

        file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));


            // User successfully inserted
            return USER_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY;
        } else {
            // Failed to create user
            return USER_CREATE_FAILED;
        }


    return $response;



    }
}
```

**upload.php**

```
    <?php

include './DbHandler.php';
$db = new DbHandler();


$response = array();

if (isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['image'] != '') {


$name = $_POST['name'];
 $image = $_POST['image'];




$res = $db->createProfile($name, $image);

if ($res == USER_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY) {


    $response["error"] = false;
    $response["message"] = "access granted";
} else if ($res == USER_CREATE_FAILED) {
    $response["error"] = true;
    $response["message"] = "Sorry! Error occurred in registration.";
} 
   } else {
    $response["error"] = true;
     $response["message"] = "Sorry! phone number is not valid or missing.";
   }

    echo json_encode($response);

   ?>
```

Comment: You're mixing OOP and procedural style. Change `mysqli_fetch_array($response)` to `$stmt->fetch_array($response)`. And before you do that, you need to actually perform the query. You're just preparing it. Since there are no placeholders in the query, you can just directly change `prepare` to `query`.

Comment: Oh and swap `function createProfile($image, $name)` to `function createProfile($name, $image)`

Comment: Thanks let me do it like that , i let you know if it works

Comment: excuse me sir for my questions.  I change      mysqli_fetch_array($response) to $stmt->fetch_array($response)  and         function createProfile($image, $name) to function createProfile($name, $image)   now i am getting this error :  Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_array() in C:

Comment: Did you change `prepare` to `query` (the line before the loop)?

Comment: Yes when i do it i get this : Warning: mysqli_result::fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be long, array given in c: ..

Comment: Oh, overseen this. Remove `$response` out of `fetch_array()` -> `$stmt->fetch_array()`

Comment: Oh, my goodness, it works . Many thanks you are life saver really, i spent whole day on this !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $response = array();

$stmt =$this->conn->prepare ("SELECT id FROM uploadimagestoserver ORDER BY       id ASC") ;

 $id = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){
        $id = $row['id'];
}
```

So say its an array and never execute your `$stmt`